# Unexpected behaviour of rewriterules in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /vixer.php?v=$1 [QSA]
```

the main problem is that when I enter www.example.com/vix_25 it goes to 404

and when I enter another url /vix25 it works.. I really dont understand what is the diffrence and why 1st  doesnt work.

Can you guys help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an underscore to the pattern so that it can match a "_" in the Requested URI

```
 ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

Try this :

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /vixer.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make it a bit more robust for your rule. Tell apache that if it's not a real file and not a real directory then rewrite it. This prevents 404's too. I also changed the regex so that it will match better instead of individually adding matches. Also I would make sure MultiViews are off.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewriterule ^([^/]+)/?$ /vixer.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```